# Vendor-specific SCSI commands reference for optical drives

Tags: scsi, optical-drive

I'm looking for references of vendor-specific SCSI commands. I'm mostly concerned about the following ones :

- `0xD4`
- `0xD5`
- `0xD8`

Based on what I know already, those commands are some "special" read commands used on some Plextor drives. However, I was not able to find any more information about them anywhere.

I am aware that such knowledge is most probably protected by burn-before-you-read NDAs, but I'd still be thankful for any information regarding those - or, for that matter, any other - vendor-specific commands.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe a simple thought but have you tried to contact plextor directly?

Comment: @fuchs777 - I used to be a member of the CDFreaks forums (now called MyCE). There was a big battle with Plextor, since one of the members of these forums published a program that allowed to do the same things as Plextor's PlexTools, bundled with some drives, and posted it to Sourceforge. Plextor threatened going on with the development of the tool with legal action. So... I don't think I'll get a "sure, here you are" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't treat this as an answer - I just saw your question as a challenge to my Googling skills and I claim no knowledge or understanding of SCSI protocols whatsoever.

I'm just posting the only definite hit I could find, in the hope that you may not have seen it and it might be useful. It's only concerning the 0xD8 OpCode.

So, from [this page](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/cam/scsi/scsi_all.c), I found this :

[image: d8]

Comment: Thanks! Your Googling skills are certainly much better than mine. :)

Comment: You were the one that was the closest (as humanly possible) with an answer, so enjoy your extra reputation. :) I'd hate my points go to waste.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar well that is most unexpected and the best Christmas present I could have wished for! Many thanks!